# SOQL - Using RecordVisibilityContext clause to filter WITH queries

Tags: soql, spring-20

In the [new SOQL changes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_api_soql.htm#rn_api_soql) in the upcoming Spring '20 release, it mentions in the **Changed Calls** section:

> Select items based on visibility. Use the new RecordVisibilityContext clause to filter WITH queries.

What does this mean and how would you use it in a sample SOQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select V48.0 on the SOQL reference page, you'll be able to find `RecordVisibilityContext`:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with.htm?search_text=RecordVisibilityContext

The parameters mentioned are `maxDescriptorPerRecord`, `supportsDomains` and `supportsDelegates`.  They seem to be related to "Visibility Services", but that is not described anywhere.

Comment: `RecordVisibilityContext` also seems related to the new [RecordVisibility](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_recordvisibility.htm#!) object, available from v46 onwards